# Admin Themes without code?

Tags: php, magento, themes

My question is, can the Magento admin pages be themed (changing of Magento logo, general layout, menu colours) without touching the core code? (perhaps by modifying the admin css?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento doesn't really let you have multiple admin themes. I think the best you'll be able to do is modify the files in app/design/adminhtml and skin/adminhtml to make any desired changes. If you're trying for a complete overhaul, this could be quite a task. If you're just looking for some simple changes, it might not be too bad.

Be aware, however, that there is HTML stuffed into some of the Blocks here and there.

Answer (score 1):

The admin theme uses the exact same rendering system as the frontend. You can even declare a new package and theme, but this has to be done in config files as there is no admin setting for it. Be aware though that if your site has the core-released Find Feed extension (look in app/code/community/ - Versions < 1.6CE and < 1.11EE), the extension adds a custom theme to the system. See the `<stores><admin>` node in `app/code/community/Find/Feed/etc/config.xml` for example syntax. Another note - there is no base/default package/theme for design fallback.

Incidentally, it would be trivial to add admin theme settings to a group in the Design section in system configuration - you just would want to make sure you don't mess up.